# How can I check if an HTML attribute is supported with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, download

I have an HTML element that downloads a file when clicked.

```html
<a href="my-file.txt" download>
  Download File
</a>
```

But, the `download` attribute isn't supported in most browsers. If it isn't supported, I want to run a function when clicked. Is this possible with jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: _"But, the download attribute isn't supported in most browsers"_ - What? It works in all browsers except Opera Mini (and IE11) -> https://caniuse.com/download

Comment: @Andreas I am using Google Chrome and the download attribute isn't supported.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you then you have either a really old version or there's something else.

Comment: It is definitely supported in Chrome